# Trouble With PHP and Nested Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested, json

I am having a hard time working with nested arrays using json_decode(). I am trying to get a list of team names.

Here is the actual array: http://pastebin.com/eMqMcucN

If you look at the array, there are three teams. The first team contains data I do not need and is not complete (but I am able to get the team name). Its the nested array where teams have complete data thats getting me. What I would like to get is the two additional team names and ignore the first team as it has no nested arrays and no real details. However, I have no problem geting the first team name as it is not nested.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I am currently using on the array above.

The line "echo 'name: ' .  $sd->name;" throws an error of "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I have tried variations but no luck.

```
$obj=json_decode($json);
$data = $obj->fantasy_content->users->{'0'}->user[1]->teams;
$userguid = $obj->fantasy_content->users->{'0'}->user->{'0'};

echo '<pre>'; 
foreach($data as $d){

    $subdata = $d->team;

    foreach($subdata as $sd){
        echo 'name: ' .  $sd->name; //this line errors
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go two levels deeper, under `team` there's another array and only this array contains the array with `name`:

```
[team] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array (
                       [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [team_key] => 273.l.73856.t.9
                            )

                       [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [team_id] => 9
                            )

                       [2] => stdClass Object
                       (
                            [name] => Team API
                       )
                       ...
                    )
                )
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is where I am having difficulty. I was thinking I need to take this line... $subdata = $d->team; and some how drill further. But, the next two levels don't seem to have a hook to drill to as they are just [0],[1] and then it goes into [0], [1], [2], etc... for each team. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, you'll need to iterate the inner-arrays using `foreach` - I don't see any way around it (unless you start using classes and objects!).